# dnsmasq: Job for dnsmasq.service failed

Tags: debian, dnsmasq

I cannot get `dnsmasq` working after the installation. The installation produces `Job for dnsmasq.service failed. See 'systemctl status dnsmasq.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.` error message. Hence reason it is not running. I removed and reinstalled again but no luck.

I couldn't find an answer/obvious solution to this issue. All people talk about is pihole which is irrelevant to me.

I am on a very freshly installed Debian Jessie box.

This is the content of [/etc/dnsmasq.conf](https://pastebin.com/uhFgML3C)

**INSTALL**

```
vagrant@experimental:~$ sudo apt-get install dnsmasq

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dns-root-data dnsmasq-base libnetfilter-conntrack3
Suggested packages:
  resolvconf
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dns-root-data dnsmasq dnsmasq-base libnetfilter-conntrack3
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
Need to get 471 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,147 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libnetfilter-conntrack3 amd64 1.0.4-1 [36.8 kB]
Get:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main dns-root-data all 2017072601~deb8u2 [15.5 kB]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main dnsmasq-base amd64 2.72-3+deb8u2 [403 kB]
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main dnsmasq all 2.72-3+deb8u2 [15.8 kB]
Fetched 471 kB in 1s (289 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libnetfilter-conntrack3:amd64.
(Reading database ... 34946 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnetfilter-conntrack3_1.0.4-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnetfilter-conntrack3:amd64 (1.0.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dns-root-data.
Preparing to unpack .../dns-root-data_2017072601~deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dns-root-data (2017072601~deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dnsmasq-base.
Preparing to unpack .../dnsmasq-base_2.72-3+deb8u2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dnsmasq-base (2.72-3+deb8u2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dnsmasq.
Preparing to unpack .../dnsmasq_2.72-3+deb8u2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dnsmasq (2.72-3+deb8u2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.22-0+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u7) ...
Setting up libnetfilter-conntrack3:amd64 (1.0.4-1) ...
Setting up dns-root-data (2017072601~deb8u2) ...
Setting up dnsmasq-base (2.72-3+deb8u2) ...
Setting up dnsmasq (2.72-3+deb8u2) ...
Job for dnsmasq.service failed. See 'systemctl status dnsmasq.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dnsmasq, action "start" failed.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.22-0+deb8u1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u7) ...
```

**VERSION**

```
vagrant@experimental:~$ dnsmasq -v

-bash: dnsmasq: command not found
```

**STATUS**

```
vagrant@experimental:~$ sudo systemctl status dnsmasq

● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/dnsmasq.service.d
           └─50-dnsmasq-$named.conf, 50-insserv.conf-$named.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-07-05 21:41:18 GMT; 1min 13s ago

Jul 05 21:41:18 experimental dnsmasq[8545]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Jul 05 21:41:18 experimental dnsmasq[8548]: dnsmasq: junk found in command line
Jul 05 21:41:18 experimental systemd[1]: dnsmasq.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 05 21:41:18 experimental systemd[1]: Failed to start dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Jul 05 21:41:18 experimental systemd[1]: Unit dnsmasq.service entered failed state.
```

-

```
vagrant@experimental:~$ systemctl status dnsmasq.service

● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/dnsmasq.service.d
           └─50-dnsmasq-$named.conf, 50-insserv.conf-$named.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-07-05 21:41:18 GMT; 6min ago
```